# Create a Lookup on nested object in list

Tags: c#

I have List.

How would i create look up from below list based on Group and Id from List where string from Group acts as Key ?

so i could have look up something like "ShelfGroup" as key and values as "Id".

```
public class A
{
    public int Id;

    public Drop Door;
}

public class Drop
{
   public List<Product> Product;
}

public class Product
{ 
   public string ShelfGroup;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question, is this what you need? `Product.GroupBy(p => p.Group)`

Comment: @StepTNT : i updated the question. I am trying to create a look for from List<A>

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear yet as your question does not match with the provided data model. Can you please add a sample input and output? Thanks.

Comment: @Hector, do you need to input ShelfGroup and List<A>, and get Id as an output??

Comment: @Youssef13, Yes. I need to search based on "ShelfGroup" and get "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on OP, here's how to do it:

```
A Lookup(string shelfGroup, List<A> items)
{
    return items.First(i => i.Door.Product.Any(p => p.ShelfGroup == shelfGroup));
}
```

please note that `Drop.Product` is `private`, you may want to make it `public` to be able to use this method.

EDIT:

use this one if want a list of items matching your condition

```
IEnumerable<A> Lookup(string shelfGroup, List<A> items)
{
    return items.Where(i => i.Door.Product.Any(p => p.ShelfGroup == shelfGroup));
}
```

Comment: His `List<Product> Product`  in the question is **not** public. It's either a mistake in the question, or it will require reflection.

Comment: Given how he edited the question, I suspect that his model is just a sample made for the question, so a mistake is more likely.

Comment: @StepTNT , i corrected the private to public. I was thinking to create a Lookup list based on different shelfGroup where it acts as "Key".  In your method it will return just one item.

Comment: @Hector, Use .Where instead of .First to return all items.

Comment: @Hector it returns one item because you asked for `A` and not for `List<A>`, but I've updated the answer with both methods.

Comment: Thanks. This will also work. I was thinking in different way.